# PermissionDeniedError: From /job:worker/replica:0/task:0

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model

I am using google colaboratory to pretrain bert.My train_data is on google cloud storage,my code is on colab

```
IS_COLAB_BACKEND = 'COLAB_GPU' in os.environ  
if IS_COLAB_BACKEND:
    from google.colab import auth
    auth.authenticate_user()
model_saved_path = 'gs://zhongxing_train/model/roberta_pretrain_model2.ckpt'
corpus_paths = ['gs://zhongxing_train/corpus.0.tfrecord' ]
tpu_address = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
```

The flowing is error message:

```
PermissionDeniedError                     Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)



1355     try:
-> 1356       return fn(*args)
   1357     except errors.OpError as e:

10 frames
PermissionDeniedError: From /job:worker/replica:0/task:0:
Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "service-555555555555@cloud-tpu.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to zhongxing_train/corpus.0.tfrecord.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "service-555555555555@cloud-tpu.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to zhongxing_train/corpus.0.tfrecord.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'
     when reading metadata of gs://zhongxing_train/corpus.0.tfrecord
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

PermissionDeniedError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1368           pass
   1369       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1370       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1371 
   1372   def _extend_graph(self):

PermissionDeniedError: From /job:worker/replica:0/task:0:
Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "service-555555555555@cloud-tpu.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to zhongxing_train/corpus.0.tfrecord.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "service-555555555555@cloud-tpu.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to zhongxing_train/corpus.0.tfrecord.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'
     when reading metadata of gs://zhongxing_train/corpus.0.tfrecord
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
```

[This is my colab cord](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1upR77mdFEST2PaFzZ15Ne65wWKg9SEbE)

I think maybe I need to set permission for my train_data on cloud storage 
How can I get permission from google cloud storage

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant your service account with `storage.objects.get` permission, which you can do by granting the service account with at least the [`Storage Object Viewer` role](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles).

You can [do it using the Cloud Console or the Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource).